# Fulltext search that filters results based on other table column value

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm searching through a table (t1) where every record is linked to t2. But only want results from t1 that are linked to t2 (where t2.rel_mag = '2')

I can't get this

```
AND t2.rel_mag = '2' AND rel_active = '1'
```

to work in the below query, which now gives all the results instead of only from: **t2.rel_mag = '2'**

```
SELECT t1.relID as relID,+ more columns,
( (1.3 * (MATCH(mag_title) AGAINST ('$_GET[search]%' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) 
+ (0.6 * (MATCH(mag_webheader) AGAINST ('%$_GET[search]%' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) ) 
AS relevance FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.relnr=t2.relid 
WHERE ( MATCH(mag_title,mag_webheader) AGAINST ('$_GET[search]%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ) 
HAVING relevance > 0  
ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT 0,15
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you that rel_active  belongs to t2

add both to the join so that one t2 will be selected that comply with both values

```
SELECT t1.relID as relID,+ more columns,
( (1.3 * (MATCH(mag_title) AGAINST ('$_GET[search]%' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) 
+ (0.6 * (MATCH(mag_webheader) AGAINST ('%$_GET[search]%' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) ) 
AS relevance FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.relnr=t2.relid AND t2.rel_mag = '2' AND t2.rel_active = '1' 
WHERE ( MATCH(mag_title,mag_webheader) AGAINST ('$_GET[search]%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ) 
HAVING relevance > 0  
ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT 0,15
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this one but it still gives all results instead of only linked to t2.rel_mag = '2'. It looks like that filter doesn't work on the t1 request.

Comment: it should have see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bVvbUy1rirBp5tD9Fq9J8X/3

Comment: Wow thanks! I now see that the actual rel_mag is NULL in the results. Don't know why that is.

Comment: t2.rel_active also turns out to be NULL in this query. Any idea what triggers that? They are among the '+ more columns' in the query above.

Comment: I would run it without the where clause and having or start completely from scratch.

Comment: Too bad, looks like I have to start from scratch then. Thanks anyway @nbk!